# tool to extract string resourses from html page

Tags: html, spring

is there any tool that extract the string resourses from my html page so I just translate them to another languages when I want to make my website support multi languages 
I am using this method to make the multi language
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you a need a text from html extractor you can use [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart).

It's pretty simple, all you have to do is:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");
   String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

You can try it your self using their [Web-API](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/).